# Sharing data between sibling components (not working as expected)

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am trying to send data from one sibling component to another but it is not working as expected

Below is the service.ts file

```
private _testIdSource = new Subject<number>();
  test_id = this._testIdSource.asObservable();

  sendTestId(test_id : number){
    console.log(test_id);//showing data
    this._testIdSource.next(test_id);
  }
```

this components takes the input from a form as id

```
addQuestions(test_id:number){
    console.log(test_id);//showing data
    
    this.service.sendTestId(test_id); 
    this.router.navigate(['/editTest']);    
    
  }
```

and this component is supposed to receive the data and initialize it to a global variable `testId` but i am having difficulty in setting the value of global variable to the received data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.test_id
      .subscribe(
        message=> {
          if(message != null){
            this.testId = message;
            console.log('test_id value received -> '+this.testId);//showing data
          }else{
            console.log('null value received');
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(this.testId);//says undefined
      
  }
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass value to sibling components using simple [TypeScript Setter and Getter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) instead of an Observable (which we must need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leak).

**service.ts**

```
test_id: number;

get testId(): string {
  return this.test_id;
}

set testId(id): string {
  this.test_id = id;
}
```

setting id via component

```
addQuestions(test_id: number) {
  this.service.testId = test_id; 
}
```

and finally getting value

```
ngOnInit() {
 const testId = this.service.testId
 console.log(testId);
}
```

Hope this address your issue.