# Angular 4 Rxjs subject subscribe is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a shared service `data.service.ts` which have

```
public pauseProjectTask$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

pauseTaskProject(taskData,type){
    this.pauseProjectTask$.next(taskData);             
}
```

and I have a `footer.component.ts` which shows currently active task in each pages, task can be paused from footer component. I have a pause function in footer.

```
pauseTask(taskData,type){
    console.log(taskData,type);
    this.pauseTaskSub = this.dataService.pauseTaskProject(taskData,type);
}
```

and I have other component which lists all tasks. `task.component.ts`. it listens for task status change.

```
this.pauseProjectTaskSub = this.dataService.pauseProjectTask$.subscribe(taskData => {
      this.changesTaskStatus('','pause',taskData);
});


ngOnDestroy(){
    this.pauseProjectTaskSub.unsubscribe();        
}
```

its unsubscribed `OnDestroy`.

when I call `pauseTaskProject()` which is in footer component it calls `pauseTaskProject()` in data.service.ts

`pauseTaskProject` is called but it didn't subscribe in `tasks.component.ts`

1. Task is started from tasks page, which is tasks.component.ts
2. Switch to other page and pause task from footer component. It doesn't work
3. It works when I don't use unsubscribe. but if unsubscribe is not used, subscribe calls multiple time.

Comment: 1. `pauseTaskProject(taskData)` function has one parameter and you're sending 2 arguments `this.....pauseTaskProject(taskData,type);`? 2. Is the function triggered before the subscription or after the subscription?

Comment: @MichaelD 1st was the typo, corrected it. 
2. When I go to tasks component it subscribes, when I go to other pages it unsubscribe.

Comment: A wild guess: Both components are in different modules, and each module provides the service. As a result each component has another instance of the service. If so, please consider providing the service in root.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Both components are in different modules its true, but `data.service` is added in proveders of `app.module`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya you already unsubscribe thats why it doesnt have data in footer, better to use TypeScript setter and getter those are simple no Observable that means no subscribe no unsubscribe.

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya check this out it should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545305/sharing-data-between-sibling-components-not-working-as-expected/

Comment: @KamranKhatti, Shouldn't it  re-subscribe when its called again?

Answer (score 0):

Give the lack of information, most probably the subscription is triggered after the function `this.dataService.pauseTaskProject(taskData,type)` is called. Subscriptions to `Subject` observable emit notifications that are pushed to it **only after** the subscription.

If you need the previously pushed value to the observable, you could either use [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) or [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject). I'll illustrate with `ReplaySubject` with buffer size 1. It'll hold/buffer the previously pushed value to it and emit it immediately upon subscription.

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

public pauseProjectTask$: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
...
```

Comment: tried  `ReplaySubject ` as you suggested, but it still doesn't  seem to work, tried `BehaviorSubject` too.

Comment: Please make sure the value is pushed to the source observable.

Comment: I can see values in console.log in `data.service`