# Angular 10 - Sharing data between sibling components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to share data between 2 sibling components.

- **Component 1:** My component 1 is my navbar and it has an option to change the app languange (using ngx- translate), this option is a select with different options.
- **Component 2:** My component 2 is a blog with different posts, this posts are saved in a MySQL DB, there are 2 possible languages, the posts are saved in different tables of the DB depending the language there are writed.

So, what we are trying to do is depending the language is selected in component 1 do an http request to the backend passing the actual language selected to get the posts from the correspondent table.

Any idea how to get the languange selected in my component 2 when the select option changes in my component 1?

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545305/sharing-data-between-sibling-components-not-working-as-expected/63545521#63545521 looks like its a duplicate one

Comment: Thanks @KamranKhatti, but this will take my select value when it changes? cause we need to get on component 2 the value of the language selected every time it changes.

Comment: Idk how you implemented ideally when component 1 value is triggered you can pass that value into component 2 using `Input`, `Output` decorators looks like its a straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ngx-translate`, you can use its service to know which language is selected rather than depending on your component.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
            // run your code
        });
    }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#translateservice) of the `ngx-translate` library for a list of all the events and properties.

Comment: Hello @David Fontes, thank you for you answer, that solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use RxJS. So you can make service which has BehaviourSubject. And then when you change value in the **1 component** you will update this BehaviourSubject value. So in **2 component** you can listen to value changes of the subject, and tigger service with different language to get called.

Here is logic within a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})

export class LanguageService {
    private _languageState: BehaviorSubject<Language> = new BehaviorSubject<Language>();

    constructor() {}

    setLanguageState(lang: Language) {
        this._languageState.next(lang);
    }

    onChangedLanguageState() {
       return this._languageState.asObservable();
    }
}
```

And then in **1 component** when language is switched just update the subject as `this.languageService.setLanguageState(lang).`

In the **2 component** listen to changes as `this.languageService.onChangedLanguageState.subscribe(() => {// call http service })`